# Can't Convert Debounce ES5 to ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, debouncing

I found a great `debounce()` function code online, but I am having a hard time converting it from ES5 to ES6.

The issue is as follows: When I use the ES5 implementation, everything works perfectly. The window is resized, `console.log()` is *immediately* triggered, and subsequent resizings are ignored until after the 500ms I specified.

However, in the ES6 implementation, the first call works immediately... but every time after that it is *also* delayed by 500ms, even after cooling down!

If there is anyone who knows what I am doing wrong, I would really appreciate some help.

Examples:

```js
function debounceES5(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function () {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

const debounceES6 = (callback, wait, immediate=false) => {
  let timeout = null
  return (...args) => {
    const callNow = immediate && !timeout
    const next = () => callback(...args)
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(next, wait)
    if (callNow) { next() }
  }
}

document.querySelector('.es5').addEventListener('click', debounceES5(() => {console.log('clicked')}, 1000, true))

document.querySelector('.es6').addEventListener('click', debounceES6(() => {console.log('clicked')}, 1000, true))
```

```html
Click both of these buttons fast and see how they react differently

<br />

<button class="es5">ES5</button>
<button class="es6">ES6</button>
```

Comment: By using the arrow function your inner function is using the wrong `this`. This one of the many cases where you can't use an arrow function since then you can never get `this` from the caller.

Comment: there is no `this` in the code @gman

Comment: why aren't you using `;` in the ES6 code? (not that it's the problem)

Comment: @JaromandaX, 1st line of the inner function of the working version is `var context = this`

Comment: @JaromandaX ES6 is a lot more forgiving, and I like it cleaner!

Comment: sorry, was looking at ES6 code only @gman

Comment: @gman But the first function works perfectly, so `this` shouldnt be a problem. The ES6 version never uses `this`

Comment: in ES5 code, the `later` function sets `timeout=null` - the equivalent isn't being done in ES6 code

Comment: @JaromandaX syntax discussions are not productive and not related to the question

Comment: Posted proof the es6 debounce doesn't handle cases the es5 does. I see the answer you accepted shows my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your ES5 function written in ES6 - without skipping ANY details (except the `context` which is not relevant)

```
const debounce = (func, wait, immediate=false) => {
    let timeout;
    return (...args) => {
        const later = () => {
            timeout = null; // added this to set same behaviour as ES5
            if (!immediate) func(...args); // this is called conditionally, just like in the ES5 version
        };
        const callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func(...args);
    };
};
```

Note, the `later` function does exactly what the ES5 version does

This should now behave (almost) identically to the ES5 version ... the whole `context = this` thing <strike>seems completely weird in the ES5 version anyway</strike> makes sense with example usage

> However, as per comments, since the code is used for event handler, `this` is quite important, it's the Event Target so, you really can't return an `arrow function`

BEtter code would be

```
const debounce = (func, wait, immediate=false) => {
    let timeout;
    return function (...args) {
        const later = () => {
            timeout = null; // added this to set same behaviour as ES5
            if (!immediate) func.apply(this, args); // this is called conditionally, just like in the ES5 version
        };
        const callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(this, args);
    };
};
```

Comment: `context = this` is not weird at all, the result of the `debounce` could be assigned as a method of an object, the recording of `context` enables such a debounced method to have an appropriate `this` when invoked.

Comment: This works! My problem was that I called `next()` on the last line, instead of `func(...args)`. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @Kaiido ... I think I'm out of my depth, since the example usage code is passing in an arrow function as the callback ... no, nevermind, both codes work identically with my amendments ... thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

You can't use arrow functions in `debounce` (well, you need to know where you can and where you can't)

Arrow function *bind* `this` when they are created. That means the `this` in an array will never and can never change.

For example

```js
'use strict';

function safeToString(v) {
  return v === undefined 
      ? 'undefined' 
      : v.toString();
}

function regularFunc() {
  console.log('regular:', safeToString(this));
}

const arrowFunc = () => {
  console.log('arrow:', safeToString(this));
};

regularFunc();
arrowFunc();

regularFunc.call("hello");
arrowFunc.call("world");
```

Notice in the `regularFunc` case `this` is undefined and later we can redefine it to `hello` but in the `arrowFunc` case it's always `[Object Window]`

So no to your ES6 debounce. Here's The supposedly working ES6 version

```
const debounce = (callback, wait, immediate) => {
    let timeout;
    return (...args) => {
      const callNow = immediate && !timeout
      const next = () => callback(...args)
      clearTimeout(timeout)
      timeout = setTimeout(next, wait)
      if (callNow) { next() }
    }
  }
```

Let's test it

```js
function es5Debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

const es6Debounce = (callback, wait, immediate) => {
  let timeout;
  return (...args) => {
    const callNow = immediate && !timeout
    const next = () => callback(...args)
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(next, wait)
    if (callNow) {
      next()
    }
  }
}

function safeToString(v) {
  return v === undefined
      ? 'undefined'
      : v.toString();
}

class Test {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  log(...args) {
    console.log(
        this ? this.name : 'undefined', 
        safeToString(this),
        ...args);
  }
}

class ES5Test extends Test {
  constructor() {
    super('ES5:');
  }
}
ES5Test.prototype.log = es5Debounce(ES5Test.prototype.log, 1);

class ES6Test extends Test {
  constructor() {
    super('ES6:');
  }
}
ES6Test.prototype.log = es6Debounce(ES6Test.prototype.log, 1);

const es5Test = new ES5Test();
const es6Test = new ES6Test();

es5Test.log("hello");
es6Test.log("world");
```

As you can see the es6 version fails because `this` is wrong. If you only ever use non-member functions then `es6Debounce` will look like it's working but as soon as you use member functions on a class or event handlers you'll see `es6Debounce` does not work, `this` is not set correctly.

The code here tries to show the error.  `ES5Class` and `ES6Class` are identical. The test should print

```
ES5: [object Object] hello
ES6: [object Object] world
```

instead it prints

```
ES5: [object Object] hello
undefined undefined world
```

As another example let's try an event handler

```js
function es5Debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

const es6Debounce = (callback, wait, immediate) => {
  let timeout;
  return (...args) => {
    const callNow = immediate && !timeout
    const next = () => callback(...args)
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(next, wait)
    if (callNow) {
      next()
    }
  }
}

function mousemove(e) {
  console.log(this.id, e.pageX, e.pageY);
}

document.querySelector('#es5')
    .addEventListener('mousemove', es5Debounce(mousemove));
document.querySelector('#es6')
    .addEventListener('mousemove', es6Debounce(mousemove));
```

```css
#es5, #es6 {
  margin: 1em;
  width: 10em;
  height: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
#es5 {
  background: orange;
}
#es6 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="es5">es5</div>
<div id="es6">es6</div>
```

Move the mouse over the 2 areas. Notice again the es6 one is wrong.

Whether or not that's important do you I have no idea but the original `debounce` you posted explicitly has code to make that case work.

Comment: For my use case it does not make a difference, but I understand how it can break code which would rely on `this`. I will use the safer code you and @jaro provided, in case I reuse this code somewhere that context is important. Thank you!

Comment: typical use case `someElement.onmousemove = debounce(somehandler)` which will fail on the es6 version above

Comment: If you look at the "use" case in the question, with the arrow function being used for the callback function, both es5 and es6 code will "fail"

Answer (score 1):

My preferred solution is the following one taken from [Chris Boakes](https://chrisboakes.com)' blog post [*Understanding how a JavaScript ES6 debounce function works*](https://chrisboakes.com/how-a-javascript-debounce-function-works/):

```
function debounce(callback, wait) {
    let timeout;
    return (...args) => {
        const context = this;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(() => callback.apply(context, args), wait);
    };
}
```

Although it does not offer `immediate` arg. is still good enough for it to be shared here.